# Unbiased estimator for binomial random variable

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, inference, binomial-distribution, point-estimation

On internet, I was reading about the point estimators. I am attaching the screenshot of the relevant portion.
[image]

Suppose we have a sample $X_1,\;X_2,\;...,\;X_n$, then the point estimator is a function T:$X_1\times X_2\times ...\times X_n\to\mathbb R$ which is used to estimate the parametric function $g(\theta)$.
In Example 1, shown in the above pic, the estimator is take as $T(\underline X)=T((X_1,\;X_2,\;...,\;X_n))= X$. I am not able to understand what is this $X$?
Shouldn't we have to define $T(\underline X) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n^2}$, because then $E(T(\underline X)) = \frac{n^2p}{n^2} = p$.
I am not able to understand what is this $X$ in the example in relation to the point estimator.

Comment: Here $X$ is $\sum_{1\leq i\leq n} X_i.$ BTW, why did you write $T$'s domain as $X_1\times X_2\times\cdots\times X_n$?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if $X=\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i$, then $E(X/n) =\frac{1}{n}E(X)=\frac{n\times np}{n}=np\neq p$ because $E(X_i)=np$.

Comment: I think that $T's$ domain will be $X_1\times X_2\times . . .\times X_n$, because $T$ is a function over the sample of size $n$ i.e, $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$

Comment: Hm. I didn't notice $X_i\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n, p). $ I rather thought each was following Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: The statement is unclear, but the author meant that you are drawing $n$ times from a Bernoulli with probability $p$, not from a Binomial with probability $p$.  The Binomial is the distribution of the sum of the $n$ draws.  The individual Bernoulli samples are designated by $X_1, \dots, X_n$, the Binomial sample is designated by $X$.  You can guess this by noticing that the random sample has $n$ elements, and the Binomial distribution's size parameter is also $n$.

Comment: Much of this language is nonsensical or nearly so.  The exercise is poor because it doesn't actually "find" estimators: it *declares* them, as if given to us by a deity or oracle, and shows they have the intended properties.  If you have a choice, please find another source for this information!

Comment: @whuber, may you recommend some source.

Comment: See what users have recommended by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=reference+wiki%3Ayes+estimation).